# Azure Webjob working fine in local but it's not working on Azure portal

Tags: c#, azure, sharepoint-2013, azure-webjobs

I have a console application that I published as webjob. The purpose of this webjob is to read the data from sharepoint site. It is working fine in local machine and I am able to read data.

However, after deploying it to Azure App service, it is not working.

Getting below error

```
[10/12/2017 04:00:43 > 60bc6a: INFO] Cannot contact site at the specified URL http://flic.farahleisure.com/Sites/FLFIN.
[10/12/2017 04:00:43 > 60bc6a: INFO]    at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext.GetFormDigestInfoPrivate()
[10/12/2017 04:00:43 > 60bc6a: INFO]    at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext.EnsureFormDigest()
[10/12/2017 04:00:43 > 60bc6a: INFO]    at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext.ExecuteQuery()
```

Here is the code

```
using System;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Security;
using Microsoft.SharePoint.Client;
using System.Net;
using SP = Microsoft.SharePoint.Client;

namespace SampleApp
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            try
            {
                using (ClientContext context = new ClientContext("http://flic.farahleisure.com/Sites/FLFIN"))
                {
                    // Use default authentication mode  
                    context.AuthenticationMode = ClientAuthenticationMode.Default;
                    context.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials;

                    // Specify the credentials for the account that will execute the request  
                    context.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(GetSPOAccountName(), GetSPOSecureStringPassword(), GetSPODomainName());
                    ListCollection collList = context.Web.Lists;
                    context.Load(collList);                  
                    context.ExecuteQuery();
                    foreach (SP.List oList in collList)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Title: {0}", oList.Title);
                    }
                    Console.WriteLine("Azure Web Job: Successfully completed.");
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                Console.WriteLine(ex.StackTrace);
            }

            Console.ReadKey();
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried  to change  code from `context.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(GetSPOAccountName(), GetSPOSecureStringPassword(), GetSPODomainName());` to  `context.Credentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials(GetSPOAccountName(), GetSPOSecureStringPassword());`?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a good [explanation](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/168175/cannot-contact-site-at-the-specified-url-on-try-clientcontext-executequery):

> You're most probably facing what is known as a "double-hop" issue:

Your client user connects and authenticate as himself against the Web app (through Windows NTLM protocol, that requires the client to know her/his password).
The Web app uses impersonation. It means the code runs under the user's identity.
With your context.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials, the call to SharePoint tries to authenticate with the user's identity, with NTLM. However, this requires the Web app to know the user's password: as it does not, the authentication fails (unless the client browses the Web app from the Web app server, in witch case it works fine).
Simplest solution here is to avoid impersonation at the Web app level (in the web.config); all requests to SharePoint will then be made Under the application pool's identity (that will require permissions under SharePoint, of course).

Another option I described here: Saving file from SharePoint Server to shared folder - Which user account?.

Comment: I think my issue is related to what you suggest. However the problem now is that my webjob is a console application and thus it doesn't have web.config file. So don't know how to handle the same in code.

Comment: @Ritesh, do you have any configurations in your app.config?

Comment: I have these settings in app.config.....<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <startup> 
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" />
    </startup>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="SPOAccount" value="xyz" />
    <add key="SPOPassword" value="pswrd" />
    <add key="SPODomain" value ="mydomain"/>
  </appSettings>
</configuration>

Answer (score 0):

Please have a try to use [SharePointOnlineCredentials](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.client.sharepointonlinecredentials.aspx), we also could get the demo code from the [Use Microsoft Azure WebJobs with Office 365.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/pnp_articles/use-microsoft-azure-webjobs-with-office-365)

```
// Use default authentication mode.
context.AuthenticationMode = ClientAuthenticationMode.Default;   
//context.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials;              
context.Credentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials(GetSPOAccountName(), GetSPOSecureStringPassword());
```

**Update:**

Please have a try to use **username@domain**, I test it on local or published on the Azure, both are working correctly on my side.

```
using (ClientContext context = new ClientContext("sharepoint url"))
  {
      // Use default authentication mode  
        context.AuthenticationMode = ClientAuthenticationMode.Default;

      // Specify the credentials for the account that will execute the request  
      var secureString = new SecureString();
      foreach (char c in "password")
      {
           secureString.AppendChar(c);
      }
      context.Credentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials("username@domain", secureString); //example username :tom@tomtest.com
      ListCollection collList = context.Web.Lists;
      context.Load(collList);
      context.ExecuteQuery();
      foreach (var oList in collList)
      {
          Console.WriteLine("Title: {0}", oList.Title);
      }
      Console.WriteLine("Azure Web Job: Successfully completed.");
    }
```

[image]

Comment: If we are using SharePointOnlineCredentials, then how can we pass DOMAIN NAME or it is not needed at all.

Comment: Please have a try to use the username:`domain\username`

Comment: It's not working even in local now. I am getting error related to NTML and seems what @RomanBorovets suggests will help me out. But the problem now is that my webjob is a console application and thus it doesn't have web.config file.

Comment: I have updated the answer, please check it. I test with account `username@domain`. It works correctly on both local and Azure webjob.

Comment: It is still not working for me. Do you think something on the sharepoint side blocking the request ? It is accessible from my corporate network and not from azure.

Comment: It may be a reason that the your SharePoint has a policy that deny the request out of  your corporate network.

Comment: Any idea @Tom how to bypass this policy or integrate the same in code or do I need to ask network team to enable/disable any port/IP

Comment: Based on my experience, you could confirm with network team/sharepoint owner whether there is any policy about deny out of your corporate ip for the sharepoint.  If there is policy setting on your network or sharepoint site, I don't think that it could be resolved by client code.